# golang - Replacing string characters by numbers golang

Tags: string, go, random

I'm trying to run this piece of code to replace a character of a string by a random number:

```
//Get the position between 0 and the length of the string-1  to insert a random number
    position := rand.Intn(count - 1)
    strings.Replace(RandomString,)

    fmt.Println("Going to change the position number: ", position)
    //Insert a random number between [0-9] in the position
    RandomString = RandomString[:position] + string(rand.Intn(9)) + RandomString[position+1:]
```

When this is executed, the output is:

```
I was going to generate..  ljFsrPaUvmxZFFw
Going to change the position number:  2
Random string:  lsrPaUvmxZFFw
```

Could anyone help me about inserting that number inside the desired string position? I didn't find any duplicate case of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use the `strconv` package to convert the `rand.Intn(9)` to the actual string value.

Comment: Done. How couldn't I remember that? :facepalm:

Comment: Remember that behind the scenes, a `string` is just a `[]byte`. When you tried to cast the `int` to a `string`, it just took the raw number `2` (which isn't a character) and tried to display it as unicode.

Comment: true, need to work more with the unicode package of go to understand that better, thanks for the fast help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no printable characters in the range `[0, 9)`. If you want an ascii value, start at 48 (`'0'`). You probably want to include 9 too, so use `rand.Intn(10)`

```
string('0' + rand.Intn(10))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
not sure which is fast if using Itoa or this!

Comment: @DavidBarranco: Itoa does more work so this is inherently going to be faster, not that it really matters much in the context of string manipulations.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, finally added using this way.
Best regards!